# Detect whether a particular font is installed

Tags: javascript, fonts

How to detect whether or not a particular font is installed using javascript only. (Disregard to whether it is enabled or not).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Matchu suggested you rightly but here is what you are looking for:

http://remysharp.com/2008/07/08/how-to-detect-if-a-font-is-installed-only-using-javascript/

Comment: That solution won't work in all cases.  It relies on a particular font being installed, but that won't always be true.

Comment: Well yes there's that too! :-)

Comment: This, despite its acceptance, is a poor, border-line link-only answer.

Answer (score 11):

The last answer was provided 11 years ago. In the meantime there are new solutions available for people who are still looking for a solution:

You could use the [`FontFaceSet`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FontFaceSet) API provided by browsers. It is currently still an experimental technology, but already available in most browsers (except IE).

[From MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FontFaceSet/check)

> The check() method of the FontFaceSet returns whether all fonts in the given font list have been loaded and are available.

Example:

```
const fontAvailable = document.fonts.check("16px Arial");
```

When using the [`check()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FontFaceSet/check) method, make sure to check if font loading operations have been completed by using the [`ready`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FontFaceSet/ready) property, which returns a `Promise` when the loading has finished:

```
let fontAvailable;
document.fonts.ready.then(() => {
    fontAvailable = document.fonts.check("16px Arial");
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn’t work on iOS. Checked and double checked. I filed a report as such on MDN’s respective Github page.

Comment: Work on Google Chrome but not on Firefox.

Comment: If you're wondering why this doesn't work with all browsers, see https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/5744 and https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/6801.

Answer (score 7):

For latest browser , the [window.queryLocalFonts()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/queryLocalFonts) method returns a Promise that fulfills with an array of FontData objects representing the font faces available locally.

for older browser, here is a solution to check if font is installed in your device in a html page.
The idea is :create a extreme narrow font and define it in css with data object url, check target font's width with this font.

Here is the example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function () {
            const context = document.createElement("canvas").getContext("2d");
            context.font = "200px SANS-SERIF"
            const TEXT_TO_MEASURE = "A";
            var FONT_WIDTH = context.measureText(TEXT_TO_MEASURE).width;
            (function () {
                var style = document.createElement("style");
                style.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
                style.textContent = `@font-face{font-family:'__DEFAULT_FONT__';src:url('data:application/font-woff;base64,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');}`;
                document.documentElement.appendChild(style);
                var handleId = null;
                (function initailizeDefaultFont() {
                    context.font = "200px __DEFAULT_FONT__";
                    var width = context.measureText(TEXT_TO_MEASURE).width;
                    if (width != FONT_WIDTH) {
                        FONT_WIDTH = width;
                        cancelAnimationFrame(handleId);
                    }
                    else if (handleId == null) {
                        handleId = requestAnimationFrame(initailizeDefaultFont);
                    }

                })();
            })();
            function checkFontAvailable(font) {
                if (/^\s*SANS-SERIF\s*$/i.test(font)) {
                    return true;
                }
                if (!font || font == '__DEFAULT_FONT__') {
                    return false;
                }

                context.font = `200px ${font.replace(/^\s*['"]|['"]\s*$/g, "")}, __DEFAULT_FONT__`;

                var width = context.measureText(TEXT_TO_MEASURE).width;

                return width != FONT_WIDTH;
            }
            this.checkFontAvailable = checkFontAvailable;
        }).apply(this);

        console.log([checkFontAvailable("arial black b"), checkFontAvailable("arial black")]);
    </script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is the test result:

```
checkFontAvailable("微软雅黑333")
false
checkFontAvailable("微软雅黑")
true
checkFontAvailable("arial")
true
checkFontAvailable("arial black")
true
```

Answer (score 2):

Put this code anywhere in your javascript file.

```
(function (document) {
    var width;
    var body = document.body;
  
    var container = document.createElement('span');
    container.innerHTML = Array(100).join('wi');
    container.style.cssText = [
      'position:absolute',
      'width:auto',
      'font-size:128px',
      'left:-99999px'
    ].join(' !important;');
  
    var getWidth = function (fontFamily) {
      container.style.fontFamily = fontFamily;
  
      body.appendChild(container);
      width = container.clientWidth;
      body.removeChild(container);
  
      return width;
    };
  
    // Pre compute the widths of monospace, serif & sans-serif
    // to improve performance.
    var monoWidth  = getWidth('monospace');
    var serifWidth = getWidth('serif');
    var sansWidth  = getWidth('sans-serif');
  
    window.isFontAvailable = function (font) {
      return monoWidth !== getWidth(font + ',monospace') ||
        sansWidth !== getWidth(font + ',sans-serif') ||
        serifWidth !== getWidth(font + ',serif');
    };
  })(document);
```

Usage

```
console.log(isFontAvailable('Arial Black'))
// Evaluates true
```

```
console.log(isFontAvailable('thisdoesntexists'))
// Evaluates false
```

Source

https://www.samclarke.com/javascript-is-font-available

Answer (score 1):

If you absolutely need a specific font, all your visitors must have current browsers. Then you can use webfonts.

If that's not an option, you must render the font on your server and serve an image.

Comment: IE6 supports downloaded fonts.

Answer (score 0):

Font family declarations should suffice to provide a fallback in case the font you want to use is not present.

But if you really need to use a special font in your site, although this uses JavaScript, I'd recommend [Cufon](http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate/) since it's the most cross-browser solution out there - there is a CSS3 fix (font-face declarations), but it doesn't work in all browsers yet.

Comment: @Pointy No, font-face won't. It's a CSS3 only feature.

Comment: @Seb That is incorrect, sir. http://webfonts.info/wiki/index.php?title=%40font-face_support_in_Internet_Explorer

Comment: @Pointy what's that link supposed to mean? That a single browser supports any given feature doesn't mean it's from one or other technology! font-face *is* CSS3, in spite of which browsers support it. What I was saying is that, while it may work on IE, it won't work *everywhere*, as you happily alleged.

Comment: Ah, well OK that makes sense.  However, to my knowledge it works in the majority of browsers in use where it makes a difference (i.e., it doesn't work in lynx, but then the basic problem here is irrelevant there too). I guess the biggest hole is pre-3.5 Firefox, right?

Answer (score -1):

How about you just do what the rest of the world does: specify the font with CSS, and offer fallbacks? No app should ever *need* to know what fonts are available, nor is there a reliable way of doing so. (You would probably have to print hidden div with the font and measure it to see if the dimensions are what you expected, but that would be extremely brittle.)

Just go for:

```
body { font-family: MyFont, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif }
```

If you want to be doing anything with the font other than display things in it if possible, consider an alternative solution.

Comment: In my case, I want to detect if an Amharic font is installed, just so you know there is a valid use case for needing to know if a particular font is installed.

Comment: What if you work in an environment which does not have CSS? e.g paper.js

Comment: No need to be a jerk about it; there might well be situations where you want to detect the presence of a font. E.g. do I try downloading the font from Google or is it already present? It's milliseconds to download, but there's an API key limit that makes minimising font pulls a good idea. Also, the question doesn't conflict with offering fallbacks etc; you can do that as well.

Comment: Some apps would need to know what fonts are available - I'm writing an e-reader web app for kids, and I've been asked to provide a list of font choices, including Comic Sans, which doesn't exist on all systems. I need to know whether it exists so I know whether to offer it as an option in a drop-down menu or not.