# How can I detect when a font is added, removed, or changed?

Tags: c#, wpf, fonts

This is different from detecting [whether](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2881645/detect-whether-a-particular-font-is-installed) a font is installed. I am making a WPF application, and I would like the app to be able to react to the user installing or uninstalling fonts in real time. How can I do this? Is there any way to interface with the Windows Font Cache Service, for example?

Comment: You receive a [WM_FONTCHANGE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/gdi/wm-fontchange) message when Fonts are installed or uninstalled. The name of the Font is not specified, but you could rebulld the list when you get the message.

Comment: You might also be able to use FileSystemWatcher to detect changes in the Fonts folder. But I've never used it for this task (I just use the message), not sure what permissions are needed.

Comment: Well, I gave it a look. FileSystemWatcher can work on the Fonts folder and you get notifications when each Font file is either created or deleted.

Answer (score 1):

As Jimi suggested, listening for `WM_FONTCHANGE` messages on my main window allows me to detect whenever a font is added or removed.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe one of 2 ways

1. The *hackiest* way is probably probably monitor the `%windir%\fonts` folder, however you will not be able guarantee they are loaded *resources* and usable yet
2. Write a dll injection unit to *hook* and proxy the `AddFontResource` / `AddFontResourceEx` Api calls, then you will know when something has loaded the font resource

You might find this useful to understand how fonts are loaded into the system

[Font Installation and Deletion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/gdi/font-installation-and-deletion)

> An application can use a font to draw text only if that font is either
>   resident on a specified device or installed in the system font table.
>   The font table is an internal array that identifies all nondevice
>   fonts that are available to an application. An application can
>   retrieve the names of fonts currently installed on a device or stored
>   in the internal font table by calling the EnumFontFamilies or
>   ChooseFont functions.
>
> ...